# Informix insert trigger: update value on same table but different record

Tags: triggers, informix

Is there any way I can get an insert trigger to update a value on the same table in a different record to the one being inserted? Informix does not seem to allow me to do this as I understand it because it doesn't let you update a value in the same table the trigger is on. I've seen suggestions where you return the value from a store procedure and use the "into" statement in the trigger but I don't think this concept works in my case because the update needs to be done on a different record to the one being inserted.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question was also asked on the ids@iiug.org mailing list, and the consensus there was that there isn't a way to do it.  I agree with the consensus.

Comment: Thanks - It is a very annoying 'feature'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was asked on the `ids@iiug.org` mailing list, and the consensus there was that there isn't a way to do it — and I agree with the consensus.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a way to do this ...

It is true that you can't directly update the same table/column you're
triggering from,  but there is a straightforward workaround using
views and "instead of" triggers that's always worked for me.

1. rename the table
2. create a view on that table, using the original name
3. create an "instead of" trigger on the view, which then writes to the original table
4. enforce use of the view by revoking all rights on the original table

Here's a real life example for the question asked - a pricelist table with date-ranges,
where other rows for the same item need to be updated whenever
an insert,update,delete is done, to avoid having date ranges
overlap (more than one price for the same date).

pricelist:

```
item    valid_from   valid_to       price
 01     2010-01-01   2013-03-15    120.00
 01     2013-04-16   2015-12-31    125.00
 01     2016-01-01   2016-05-05    130.00
 01     2016-05-06                 140.00
```

First, replace the table with a view of the same name:

```
RENAME TABLE pricelist TO pricelist_table;
CREATE VIEW pricelist AS SELECT * FROM pricelist_table;
REVOKE ALL ON pricelist_table FROM public;
GRANT ALL ON pricelist TO public;
```

Now do an insert trigger that updates other rows of the same table
underlying the view (in this example to avoid overlapping from/to dates).
By juggling the view and table names you can also avoid errors about
updating a table referenced in a subquery (the second update in the trigger).

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_pricelist INSTEAD OF INSERT ON pricelist
       REFERENCING new AS new
   FOR EACH ROW (

     -- write the data to the real table
     insert into pricelist_table
     values(new.item,new.valid_from,new.valid_to,new.price),

     -- close off the previous price row by setting its "valid_to" date
     update pricelist_table set valid_to = new.valid_from - 1
      where item = new.item and valid_from < new.valid_from
        and ( valid_to >= new.valid_from or valid_to is null ),

     -- if the row we're inserting has a null "valid_to" date,
     -- set it to the day before the next "valid_from" date
     update pricelist set valid_to =
          (select min(valid_from)-1 from pricelist_table
            where item = new.item and valid_from > new.valid_from)
      where item = new.item and valid_from = new.valid_from
        and valid_to is null
   );
```

On later versions (11+) that support procedures with trigger references,
a better and more maintainable approach is to call a separate stored procedure
from the trigger(s):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE write_pricelist()
       REFERENCING old AS old  new AS new  FOR pricelist;

  -- do all your inserts, updates, etc to pricelist_table here ...

END PROCEDURE;

-- These triggers all call the same stored procedure (above).
CREATE TRIGGER ins_pricelist INSTEAD OF INSERT ON pricelist
    REFERENCING new AS new
    FOR EACH ROW (
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE write_pricelist() WITH TRIGGER REFERENCES
    );
CREATE TRIGGER upd_pricelist INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON pricelist
    REFERENCING new AS new old AS old
    FOR EACH ROW (
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE write_pricelist() WITH TRIGGER REFERENCES
    );
CREATE TRIGGER del_pricelist INSTEAD OF DELETE ON pricelist
    REFERENCING old AS old
    FOR EACH ROW (
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE write_pricelist() WITH TRIGGER REFERENCES
    );
```